# Reports - Combine Lead Statuses in a report

Tags: reports-api

My lead statuses are as follows:

1. Unqualified,
2. Qualified,
3. Applied,
4. Assessed,
5. Rejected,
6. Waitlisted and
7. Accepted.

I want to create a report that combines the sum of more than one status to form new columns as follows:

- Prospecting = Total Count of Unqualified Leads + Total Count of Qualified
- Review = Applied + Assessed
- Decided = Rejected + Waitlisted + Accepted

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Bucketing](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_bucketing_overview.htm&language=en_US). This [high level overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq1TkYzT-mM) is an excellent starting point. You must have the 'Create and Customize Reports' AND 'Report Builder' [user permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_bucketing_adding.htm) in order to achieve this.

This [link](https://www.minddigital.com/how-to-create-bucket-fields-in-your-salesforce-reports/) shows how you can add a bucket field on a report for the status field on the lead object.

Once you have bucketed the lead status field, you can simply change the report type from Tabular to Summary and group on that bucketed field to get the count of the different lead statuses.

From that, you can build a nice report chart and, if required, use the source report as a dashboard component on a dashboard.